# How can i change to my drawerMenuBar background colors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is my code, i've been able to change the drawerheader to black, but the when i did `color: Colors.grey[800]` for the listtiles, only it's area is covered in grey, the remaining extra space is white..

```
drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 130,
                    child: DrawerHeader(
                      child: new Text(
                        'Hi Bolade',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                          title: Text('Dashboard'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.tree),
                          title: Text('Savings'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                          title: Text('Investments'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.account_box_sharp),
                          title: Text('Products'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.wallet_membership),
                          title: Text('Wallet'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                          title: Text('Cards & Bank'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                          title: Text('Share & Earn'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.chat),
                          title: Text('Support'),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMWDa.jpg)
Image of the current state here below

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your current result and what is your expected result if possible.

Comment: Like I and the other answers suggested, wrap your main listview(one that comes after Drawer) with a container of height = screens height and grey[800] color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrap your Driver with Theme widget and replace `canvasColor`

```
  drawer: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.grey[800]),
    child: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 130,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Hi Bolade', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('Dashboard'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                title: Text('Savings'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                title: Text('Investments'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.account_box_sharp),
                title: Text('Products'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.wallet_membership),
                title: Text('Wallet'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                title: Text('Cards & Bank'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                title: Text('Share & Earn'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.chat),
                title: Text('Support'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

also in this case you don't need Container above Column anymore
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep your listview inside a Container and give a color to this container.

```
Container(
color: Colors.grey[800]
child: ListView(
.... 
)
)
```

Comment: Drawer>  Expanded > Container > Listview

I think your container is not taking full height of the screen.
Try this one and change container's color.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you question completely .....But I'm guessing that the header is black as expected, but only the tiles are covered in the grey color and the remaining space is white.(the default color).

If this is the case then you can maybe wrap your listview with a container and give it the grey color. By doing this the newly added grey container will act as a background color.

Comment: This is how it is in the question, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Keep your listview inside a Container and give a color to this container.

```
    Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    color: Colors.grey[800]
    child: ListView(
    .... 
    )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works... but the little white on top still shows.